# LINQ query any of the properties contains string

Tags: c#, linq, collections

How to query collection of type T, to return all items of T, where any of T's properties contains some string?

EDIT:

Assume that I convert each property to string before check if contains.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far, and what problems have you had with your implementation?

Comment: Does `42` contain any string? Maybe some sample code would make the question more clear...

Comment: @Downvoter Please put the reason in the comments. Try to help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You mean something like this ?

```
list.Any(x => x.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Any(p =>
            {
                var value = p.GetValue(x);
                return value != null && value.ToString().Contains("some string");
            }));
```

This could be more efficient if you get the type and the properties only once:

```
var type = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
var properties = type.GetProperties();
var result = list.Any(x => properties
            .Any(p =>
            {
                var value = p.GetValue(x);
                return value != null && value.ToString().Contains("some string");
            }));
```

**Note:** if you want to check whether or not any of the properties contains some string, use `Any`, if you want also get the items that matches with your criteria use `Where` method instead of first `Any`. Use `list.Where(x => properties.Any(...));`

Comment: Accepting this answer because it has 2 examples. Thanks.

Comment: More efficient, indeed. You should just replace the first Any by a Where, I think.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I thought OP wants to check only instead of filtering the items, the question wasn't clear enough.anyway I have added a note to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

you can use reflection (this version is not efficient, but you've got the idea).

```
myList.Where(m => m.GetType().GetProperties().Any(x => x.GetValue(m, null) != null && x.GetValue(m, null).ToString().Contains("someString"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I will have to go with reflection.

Comment: @eomeroff As opposed to?

Comment: @Servy As opposed of knowing the properties in compile time. It was my response for efficiency warning.